# Is it possible to develop a database app in Visual Studio 2010 for Microsoft SQL Server, then use MySQL instead?

Tags: sql, mysql, linq-to-sql

The dev tools for SQL in Visual Studio are great.

Is it possible to develop an app for Microsoft SQL Server, and then deploy a MySQL-compatible database instead?

The dev tools for Microsoft SQL Server are really nice (i.e. LINQ support), but a MySQL-compatible column database has better performance for huge datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use MySql .net connector

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net.html

With this, you get some of the functionality that you have with SQL server (entity framework, designer, etc) there are still a bunch of things that are not supported, but it's a good start

Comment: ADO.NET is definitely the way to go, as it is officially supported by Microsoft going forward. LINQ to SQL (or LINQ to MySQL with a connector such as dblinq) is a separate technology not officially supported by Microsoft any more. There is a lot of discussion on the web concerning ADO.NET vs. LINQ to SQL, with the majority opinion (and official Microsoft recommendations) seeming to tip the scales towards ADO.NET. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but a number of specifics might tend to prevent a full implementation on SQL Server, particularly with respect to stored procedures.

However, if the intent is to build a scaffolding on VisStudio and  finish the development using the MySQL tools, it would work okay.  You'll have to learn both SQLs quite thoroughly.  The sooner you do that, the less grief there will be in the conversion.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it will work. I don't need stored procedures, fortunately, and I can use LINQ + dblinq as an abstration layer inbetween my C# code, and the end database in either MySQL and SQL.

Answer (score 1):

One method for doing this would be to abstract away the database itself.  That be done at least a couple of ways; the first way, you could use classes to build the SQL that your application requires, and then just use that; then all that has to happen is that it has to know how to generate the right SQL for the right server.  One of the drawbacks of doing it that way, though, is that if you depend on functionality that exists on only one DBMS, you'll have to emulate it in that abstraction layer.

The other method that you could use is to create two versions of your classes that talk to the RDBMS, one for MySQL and one for Microsoft's SQL Server.  Use an interface and derive from it in order to do the actual implementation.  Of course, you'll want to make sure that the only responsibility of the class is to interact with the database, so if you're doing this for business layer objects, you'll be implementing those sorts of things with two classes: a low-level one for the database API, and a high-level one for actually providing the API that your application is going to consume.

Comment: I agree, abstraction is the way to go. I think I'll use LINQ as the abstraction layer for querying the data.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not a direct answer to your question, but the [dblinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/) project may be of use to you.

It may be worth a look just to see the MySQL implementations within the project in order to determine what the real differences between SQL Server and MySQL are going to be and how they're going to affect you.  The more you can abstract out those differences behind a dependency implementation, the easier it'll be to swap out one implementation for another.

Comment: I'd like to work at the LINQ level, and dblinq looks really nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code for SQL Server and then switch to [Devart LinqConnect](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/).
For example, you can create a LINQ to SQL model using Entity Developer (in VS integration mode or in standalone mode), then change the connection to the MySQL-specific one and run Update Database from Model wizard (don't forget to select the Regenerate Storage check box).
As a result, you will obtain a MySQL database, having structure identical to the SQL Server one.